# I have yearned for a/the chance to speak to a true geometer

Tags: articles

From [a short stor](http://dailysciencefiction.com/science-fiction/science-fiction/j-s-bangs/the-heresy-of-friar-travolo)y:

> I showed it to him. He seized the pages with immediate pleasure, as if greeting an old friend. "Would you like to work through it? I have yearned for **the** chance to speak to a true geometer."

Would it be grammatical to change the article:

> I showed it to him. He seized the pages with immediate pleasure, as if greeting an old friend. "Would you like to work through it? I have yearned for **a** chance to speak to a true geometer."

It seems to me that the second option is better. The hero yearned for *any chance* to speak to a true geometer, after all, not for this particular chance. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It's an extremely fine distinction that barely means anything at all in this exact context. But if you'll [*give me **a** chance to*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give+me+a+chance+to%2Cgive+me+the+chance+to&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgive%20me%20a%20chance%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20me%20the%20chance%20to%3B%2Cc0) explain, I'll just say that using the ***indefinite*** article more strongly acknowledges that *there might not in fact **be** any such chance* (***the*** implies it does exist, even if not currently available).

Comment: _the_ chance does not refer to this specific chance. In this usage, _the_ is referring to any real chance of meeting a geometer. So it does mean _any chance_ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A" would be valid/grammatical as well, but "the" is a little bit better because the snippet of the story you've presented describes **the** actual chance the character is having, at that moment, "to speak a true geometer."

Comment: But he says he had yearned for this even before the event. Does this mean that he yearned exactly for this chance, not just for any chance?

Comment: Like I said in my original post, they're both grammatical and get the same main idea across. To echo what FumbleFingers said, there is a fine distinction, and frankly, it doesn't matter that much in this context. If I had to choose, though, I'd still pick the one with "the" because it sounds better to me.